Restructuring Wide Data to Long Data
I'm trying to reorganise my dataframe to make analysis easier.
Currently Data looks like:
current data apparance
and I want to reorganise in a long format to look like:
ideal data appearance
If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this it would be much appreciated
I have tried grouping data using dplyr but keep running into issues

Don't post pictures of data, but rather the output of dput().

A solution with two pivot_*() and separate().
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("Language", "Text", "name"), sep = " ") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

